# Convert four Digit number into hour format SQL

Tags: sql, casting, intersystems-cache

I have looked into Cast and Convert, but I cannot find a way to do this. I need to convert four digits into an hour format. For instance, 0800 would become 8:00 or 1530 would become 15:30. I cannot use functions, I'm using a InterSystem's CacheSQL. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
If it is any more convenient, I can just divide the four digits by one hundred to get values like 15 from original 1500, or 8.30 from 0830. Does this make converting to hour:minute format easier?

Comment: What SQL implemenation are you using? SQL Server/T-SQL? Oracle? DB2? MySql? date/time manipulation is probably the one area of SQL that varies most from vendor to vendor.

Comment: It is not any of those. I am not sure what it is, I asked my boss and he said it is a totally different form. It is often similar to Oracle. But if you can give me a function name, I can look it up in our documentation, I just need somewhere to start!

Comment: Can you use custom embedded processes?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to in-depth SQL, if you mean functions and things like that, no I cannot.

Comment: Can you use CAST?  How do you do string concatenation?

Comment: String concatenation is done with double pipes: '||'

Comment: Could you show me how I would use CAST? Like CAST (Start_Time AS *WHATGOESHERE?*)

Comment: Do you want the result to be a string representation like "8:00" or a real DateTime/Time type ?

Comment: Yes it is a string representation

Comment: If you just need to insert a ":" in the middle, just do: `select substring(col, 1, 2) + ':' + substring(col, 3, 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CacheSQL, you can do this:

```
SELECT {fn TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM LEFT(col_name, 2) || ':' || RIGHT(col_name, 2)) }
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it is something like Oracle you might have a try with the `to_date()` function.

Read more [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).

Example:

```
SELECT to_date(yourColumn, 'HH24MI') FROM ...
```

**EDIT** (why? see comments): If necessary (I'm actually not familiar with Oracle) you can wrap another function like TIME() around it.

```
SELECT TIME(to_date(yourColumn, 'HH24MI')) FROM ...
```

Read more about [TIME() here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time).

```
</EDIT>
```

In MySQL the equivalent would be the `STR_TO_DATE()` function:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(yourColumn, '%H%i') FROM ...
```

Read about [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and its [parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) under the DATE_FORMAT() function.

Comment: That's a start! It did recognize that function, however I do not need it in year--mm-dd. I need it in hh:mm

Comment: Don't get confused by the function name, it will get you hh:mm . At least I can say this for sure for MySQL, but I bet it's the same for Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, it's still converting it to a yyyy-mm-dd format or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008, given data that looks like

```
create table #data
(
  HHMM int not null ,
)
insert #data values ( 0800 )
insert #data values ( 0815 )
insert #data values ( 1037 )
insert #data values ( 2359 )
```

You can say:

```
select * ,
       strTime = right( '0' + convert(varchar, HHMM / 100 ) , 2 )
               + ':'
               + right( '0' + convert(varchar, HHMM % 100 ) , 2 ) ,
       myTime  = convert(time ,
                   right( '0' + convert(varchar, HHMM / 100 ) , 2 )
                 + ':'
                 + right( '0' + convert(varchar, HHMM % 100 ) , 2 ) ,
                 120
                 )
from #data
```

Other SQL implementations likely have similar functionality.

In earlier versions of SQL Server that lack the `time` datatype, just use `datetime`, thus:

```
select * ,
       strTime = right( '0' + convert(varchar, HHMM / 100 ) , 2 )
               + ':'
               + right( '0' + convert(varchar, HHMM % 100 ) , 2 ) ,
       myTime  = convert(datetime,
                   right( '0' + convert(varchar, HHMM / 100 ) , 2 )
                 + ':'
                 + right( '0' + convert(varchar, HHMM % 100 ) , 2 ) ,
                 120
                 )
from #data
```

You'll get a `datetime` value that is 1 Jan 1900 with the desired time-of-day.

Answer (score 0):

```
left( case when (EndTime / 100) < 10 then  ('0'+ convert(varchar, EndTime / 100 )) else convert(varchar, EndTime / 100 )  end, 2 )
                 + ':'
                 + right( '0' + convert(varchar, EndTime % 100 ) , 2 )
```

Comment: You should explain your answer!